# Extensions Library REST documentJsonService and how to manage server side validation and error reporting?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using REST control from extensions library (part of Domino 9) and things work smooth. Now I'm trying to figure out how to manage server side validation and error reporting when creating a new or saving existing document. I can see e.g. 'QuerySaveDocument' hook but I cant find any documentation on how to don't allow saving document when I find some inputs not valid  and how to report / get back some validation error? Any hint here?